# Can I register a new app to existing GCM server?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

The app I am currently working on must implement push service. We have an alternative app that is developed using JavaScript and such and is developed in parallel (different package name, etc). That app already has push implemented and a server working. 
I was given the server URL and a senderID which i used like this (based on guides):

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(ServerRequests.senderId,
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Then i used the token to register on the server as instructed.
The problem is I am not receiving any messages. Is there something I missed? Will it work without having to make modifications (highly unlikely) on the server ?

Answer (score 1):

Check is api-key is valid using the method from here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http

**Checking the validity of an API key**
If you receive authentication errors when sending messages, check the validity of your API key. For example, on Android, run the following command:

```
# api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

If you receive a 401 HTTP status code, your API key is not valid. Otherwise you should see something like this:

```
{"multicast_id":6782339717028231855,"success":0,"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

If you want to confirm the validity of a registration token, you can do so by replacing "ABC" with the registration token.